# Twig: Variable in format function

Tags: php, templates, twig

I'm passing in a string to `login_create_account_label` which is:

```
Not a member? %sCreate a Free account%s.
```

And also `login_create_account_url` which has a value of:

```
http://localhost/register/
```

Due to the first format variable having HTML I've also passed in the `raw` option for this element.

```
<p class="highlight">
    {{ login_create_account_label | format('<a href="{{ login_create_account_url }}">', '</a>') | raw }}
</p>
```

I've been unable to get it to output as I want it to.

Expected (Source HTML):

```
<p class="highlight">
    Not a member? <a href="http://localhost/register/">Create a Free account</a>.
</p>
```

What I'm getting:

```
<p class="highlight">
    Not a member? 0Create a FREE account</a>.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig string manipulation can be a little tricky as there's a bunch of tools available.

Instead of outputting the variable using the output ( {{...}} ) syntax, consider converting your operand to a string using the '~' operator.  You can read more about it here.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators

```
<p class="highlight">
{{ login_create_account_label|format('<a href="' ~ login_create_account_url ~ '">', '</a>')|raw }}
</p>
```